# Stored Procedure Addition - Check if DB exists before proceeding

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm current writing a stored procedure which does several things but I want to implement a change at the start which will cause the USP to proceed no further if the variable result which provides a Database Name does not exist.

Below is my current code which is used.

Basically, if the @DBName does not exist on the server, I want the stored procedure to proceed no further, but if it does exist, then I want to proceed.

```
DECLARE @FullyQualifiedTableName VARCHAR(100) = '[Sandbox].[Test].[USP_Test]';
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(50) =
        (
            SELECT LEFT(@FullyQualifiedTableName, CHARINDEX('.', @FullyQualifiedTableName) - 1)

   );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to query the dictionary.

```
...
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM sys.databases
                      WHERE name = @dbname)
BEGIN
  -- whatever you want to do if the database doesn't exist
END;
...
```

Comment: Alternatively, `IF DB_ID(@dbname) IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FullyQualifiedTableName VARCHAR(100) = '[Sandbox].[Test].[USP_Test]';
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT LEFT(@FullyQualifiedTableName, CHARINDEX('.', @FullyQualifiedTableName) - 1));

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @DBName)
BEGIN
  -- Your logic if DB Name Exists
END;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @DBName)
BEGIN
  -- Your logic if DB Name Not Exists
END;
```

`SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [SomeTable]` Here this query will return any 1 matching record it will satisfy the criteria.

`IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS` are mainly used to check conditions. It will always return true or false based on your query.